# How to synchronize sonatype nexus with svn

Tags: svn, nexus, tagging

Is there a way to synchronize sonatype nexus and svn? Or how can I handle tagging feature with sonatype nexus?

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21601338/whats-the-difference-between-nexus-and-svn

Comment: Use an automated build server like Jenkins. Build each release, create a tag in sbubversion and push the built binary into Nexus.